# gridview displaying error message "ddldept' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
//my ddl<br>
asp:DropDownList ID="ddldept" DataTextField="dept_name" DataValueField="deptID" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>                    

//my code behind   

       protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
            txtusername.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
            txtcity.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
            txtdesignation.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;



               hiddenid.Value = row.Cells[3].Text;
//here iam getting error<br>
                ddldept.SelectedValue = row.Cells[4].Text.ToString().Trim();  


}
```

iam fetching dropdownlist values from database table.when iam selecting the row in the grid view.....iam getting the error as" ddldept has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value".

//BINDING DATA FROM DATABASE TO DROPDOWNLIST

private void filldept()

```
    {

         ddldept.DataSource = ds;

        ddldept.DataTextField = "dept_name";

        ddldept.DataValueField = "deptID";

        ddldept.DataBind();

       ddldept.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
```

}

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you have in row.Cells[4]? It looks like this value isn't being found in your ddldept.

Comment: string values(IT,HR,SALES)...thank you got the solution for that :)

Comment: ddldept.selecteditem.text=row.Cells[4].Text;